# How to bypass a firewall which asks for username and password

Tags: firewall, openvpn, bypass

Here in my college we have a firewall installed by Fortinet. 
Whenever we open Firefox it asks for a username and password ...
Once we enter that, accessing the internet is possible but with very very limited sites. Can you help in finding out a way to bypass this firewall. 
I cannot even open the websites which teaches how to make the openvpn server. So it may be Thankful if you may give the description on your page only ,rather pointing a link to do the same

Answer (score 5):

I think your college knows why they restrict your web access.

If you nonetheless want to hack this, some useful links are found below. The method described (via the proxytunnel program) requires some effort on your side to minimize the preconditions on corporate side:

- [DAG: Tunneling SSH over HTTP(S)](http://dag.wieers.com/howto/ssh-http-tunneling/)
- [SSL support with Apache and Proxytunnel](https://superuser.com/questions/145129/ssl-support-with-apache-and-proxytunnel)

proxytunnel probably is one of the most general and elaborate methods known today to bypass any corporate firewall/web proxy. It even works when a full layer-7 firewall is in effect allowing access to any website, any protocol and any port.

Comment: I tried the Second Method .. but that requires downloading a proxytunnel ...and that is just not possible with the Firewall active on the server .. Anyways i will try to see the first link, which you gave , from other place ! hope I might get a solution there ...